# Best way to trigger rewrite rules

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I typically call the rewrite rules with this action

```
add_action('init', 'add_my_rewrite_rules')
```

But what I do not like about it is that the rewrite rules are written every time an `init` action is triggered, which means pretty much every time a page is refreshed.

Is this the correct action to call the rewrite rules? Is there a better way of handling that? (i.e, no need to add the rules every time we trigger `init`)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init` is the recommended hook and no, the rewrite rules will not be overwritten each time the hook fires or that the page is loaded, *unless* if you call [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/) or [`WP_Rewrite::flush_rules()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/flush_rules/) in your callback.

```php
add_action( 'init', 'add_my_rewrite_rules' );
function add_my_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( ... );
    flush_rewrite_rules(); // don't do this
}
```

So please don't do that, or do it only upon plugin/theme activation and deactivation — and if you don't already know, you can easily flush the rules by simply going to the Permalink settings admin page, without having to hit the Save Changes button.